# How to specify project npm registry inside package.json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-registry

I am working on multiple projects at the same time and the node module registry for different projects are not the same.

For example, all modules for project **A** are from `http://registroy.foo.com` and modules for project **B** are all from `http://registroy.bar.com`

Is there a way we can specify the registry we want to use for the project inside `package.json` file, something like `source` defined inside a Gemfile in Ruby.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, but you can use an [`.npmrc`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#npmrc-files) file in the root directory of your project to specify the [`registry`](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#registry).

```
registry=http://registroy.foo.com
```